# Create a mesh from a point cloud using trimesh

Tags: graphics, 3d, mesh, 3d-reconstruction

I am trying to Create a simple triangle mesh from a point cloud using `trimesh`. I don't have face normals or the vertex ordering (the *faces* attribute in trimesh). The mesh that I am trying to reconstruct is a simple curved plane. It does not need to be watertight.

The library `open3D` has a few methods to estimate normals from a point cloud and generate a mesh. This can be done using the [Ball Pivoting method](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.html#open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_ball_pivoting), [Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.html#open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_poisson), and a few other methods.

I am looking for similar ways to create a mesh using `trimesh`. The closest approach I found reading the documentation as well as other people's questions is to use the *convex_hull* attribute of a PointCloud. However this method often fails, especially when the points lie on a plane. Thank you for any suggestions you might have.

Comment: My question would be: why do you want to do this using trimesh? From looking at the github repo, the trimesh library does not provide the functionality you are looking for. That is, you would need to implement the meshing yourself. To me, it seems like you are trying to back the wrong horse here. Why not just use Open3D, if you have already found out that it would work there? (or another library that can work with point clouds, if you don't like Open3D)

Comment: @kroneml I like Open3D, but my code needs to run on a machine that runs Linux CentOS 7. Unfortunately Open3D is not compatible with CentOS 7 - hence why I need to find an alternative.